# Convert field from string_long to text_long

Tags: entities, 9

I need to convert a field on a paragraph from the `string_long` type to the `text_long` type.

There is data in the field so I can't change it in the UI.

How would I do this programmatically?

Comment: Does this help https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/choice-entity-type-2641828-5.patch ?

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/uyidlq/updating-the-storage-definition-of-entities-that-already-have-content-in-drupal-8

Comment: I don't think that example works for this case. I get an error "Unknown column 'field_paragraph_variant_summary' because a text_with_summary field has extra columns on the storage table. I'll try adding the columns manually but that seems hacky.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution I came up with based on the example code provided by https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/71454/miststudent2011. I had to adapt it a bit for this specific case:

```
/**
 * Convert plain text field to formatted text field.
 */
function mymodule_update_9002() {
  $entity_type = 'paragraph';
  $field = 'field_paragraph_variant';

  // Retrieve existing field data.
  $database = \Drupal::database();
  $tables = [
    "{$entity_type}__$field",
    "{$entity_type}_revision__$field",
  ];
  $existing_data = [];
  foreach ($tables as $table) {
    // Get the old data.
    $existing_data[$table] = $database->select($table)
      ->fields($table)
      ->execute()
      ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }

  // Get the field config.
  $field_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('field_storage_config');
  $field_storage_config = $field_storage->loadByProperties(['field_name' => $field]);

  foreach ($field_storage_config as $field_storage) {
    // Save the config as an array and change the type.
    $new_field_storage = $field_storage->toArray();
    $new_field_storage['type'] = 'text_long';

    // Delete the original field, otherwise the new table columns won't get added.
    $field_storage->delete();

    // Re-create the field.
    $new_field_storage = $field_storage->create($new_field_storage);
    $new_field_storage->enforceIsNew(TRUE);
    $new_field_storage->save();
  }

  // Restore the data.
  foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $insert_query = $database
      ->insert($table)
      ->fields([
        'bundle',
        'deleted',
        'entity_id',
        'revision_id',
        'langcode',
        'delta',
        $field . '_value',
        $field . '_format',
      ]);
    foreach ($existing_data[$table] as $row) {
      $row[$field . '_format'] = 'subscriber_text';
      $insert_query->values(array_values($row));
    }
    $insert_query->execute();
  }
}
```